# How to configure Elastix inboud route using callerId?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I have been searching for a way to use inbound route to do some sort of mapping that depends on the caller Id , so for example:

if a call was received to a specific number that is mapped inside Elastix , and the number is 52217458 it will redirect that to a specific number , as individual no problem ,

my idea that I want to use is not one by one , what I need is inbound route caller Id to match some format ,

so if any number that starts with 522* it will be redirected to some number , and other than that , reject it ??

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment above , you can specify the caller id using regex , depending on the prefixes that you may want to include in the inbound route

my case was as to permit the callerId who has _9! starting with 9 at the beginning

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Just leave empty did field and set callerid field in inbound route(second field)

Comment: but I need to specify destination according to caller Id ,  but I think I have found a solution , we can specify a regex _ XXX !